# Symmetric L-groups of integral group ring of finite cyclic groups

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology

Where can i find the results about $L^{\ast}(\mathbb{Z}\pi)$ for $\pi$ a finite cyclic group?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The symmetric $L$-groups $L^*(Z[\pi])$ for finite cyclic groups $\pi$ have never been computed, perhaps for lack of applications: do you have any? In principle, it is possible to extend the known calculations (mainly due to Wall himself) of the quadratic $L$-groups $L_*(Z[\pi])$ to the symmetric $L$-groups. The failure of 4-periodicity in the symmetric $L$-groups was studied by Gunnar Carlsson in his 1979 paper *Desuspension in the symmetric $L$-groups*. In his 1985 paper *Surgery and the generalized Kervaire invariant*  Michael Weiss interpreted the relative $L$-groups $\widehat{L}^*(Z[\pi])$ (which are 8-torsion) in the long exact sequence
$$\dots \to L_*(Z\pi) \to L^*(Z[\pi]) \to \widehat{L}^*(Z[\pi]) \to L_{*-1}(Z[\pi]) \to \dots$$
as the twisted $Q$-groups $Q_*(B,\beta)$ of the universal chain bundle $(B,\beta)$ of $Z[\pi]$. The twisted $Q$-groups are homological in nature and so much more computable then either the quadratic or the symmetric $L$-groups, which by definition are generalized Witt groups. See Chapters 2 and 9 of my 1992 book *Algebraic $L$-theory and topological manifolds* for the general theory. Example 9.17 computes $L^0(Z[Z_2])$, which is a start!

Comment: Thank you very much for the nice answer.Do you know some other references where people analyze in detail about the symmetric signatures? Thanks again!

Comment: There are 14 references to symmetric $L$-groups on Mathematical Reviews - do you have access to MR?

Comment: Yes,I have access to MR.I do not know if the references there are really helpful.I am more interested in the symmetric signature of a space (since they are sitting in the symmetric L group,that's why i am asking this question).Given a space,how people compute its symmetric signature? are there some nice examples in the literature? Thanks.

Comment: You could also look for "symmetric signature" on MR,although only some of the hits are relevant. The symmetric signatures of manifolds (as opposed to Poincare duality spaces) are determined by the characteristic class formulae of Wall, Taylor and Williams (references in my book) and the assembly map. These are non-simply-connected analogues of the Hirzebruch signature formula. My favourite examples of symmetric signatures are the point (a 0-dimensional manifold) and the tori $T^n=S^1\times S^1 \times \dots \times S^1$, since I know how to compute the symmetric $L$-groups of $\{1\}$ and $Z^n$.